R shiny observe() function sees updateSelectInput() as an "environment," and wants a "data.frame"
Problem
I have a Shiny app in which I would like a selectInput to only take the unique values that are in the data. In the below example, even though Man is a possible value in the real world, it is not in the data, so I want the dropdown values to only include Woman and Child. When I run the below minimum working example, I recieve this error:
Warning: Error in : `x` must be 'data.frame', not 'environment'.
  47: hypothesize_fn
  46: predicate
  44: check_type
  43: calculate
  41: observe
  40: server [#2]
   3: runApp
   2: print.shiny.appobj
   1: <Anonymous>
Error : `x` must be 'data.frame', not 'environment'.

This error persists on three different machines (one Windows, Mac, and Linux), as well as when I deploy to shinyapps.io (it is present in the logs). I've also run the example code found here and here, and get errors, although different ones. It has worked before, but it started breaking a couple nights ago, and reverting back to a previously working version doesn't fix it.
The reason I cant just pass sort(unique(data$cat1)) into the selectInput() directly is because in my full working project, ui.R and server.R are two different files, and the data is only loaded into server.R. Thanks, all.
Minimum working example
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble("cat1" = c("Woman", "Woman", "Child"), "cat2" = c("b", "c", "c"))

ui <- page_navbar(
  sidebar = sidebar(
    selectInput(
      "filter_category",
      "Categories:",
      choices = NULL,
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "filter_category", 
      choices = sort(unique(data$cat1)),
      selected = sort(unique(data$cat1))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Possibly related question here, but it hasn't helped so far.
I have tried:

Reverting to a previously-functional version. The error persists now.
Removing the observe() function and returning to static selectInput choices (this works but itsn't the functionality I want).
Switching between a Mac, Windows, and Linux machine.
Deploying to shinyapps.io and using whatever environment they use there.
Manually setting choices and selected with static vectors inside of the updateSelectInput function.

I was expecting:
A dropdown selectInput in my UI that only contains the levels of the cat1 categorical variable that are present in the data.

In selectInput the inputId is filter_categories, but in updateSelectInput it is filter_letter. Is this a typo? If I make the inputId parameters the same, I don't have any error message and the the correct options are listed in the drop down menu.

Yes, this was a typo, I'm sorry. Fixed now. Good to know that it worked on your machine though.

Solution found:
For the curious, I found a solution to my own issue, and I am a little embarrassed. In an amateur mistake, I had a name conflict in my environment. Turns out, my app was calling infer::observe() instead of shiny::observe(). Replacing all of my observe() calls with shiny::observe() fixed the issue. My minimal working example only failed because I had already loaded conflicting packages before writing the example.
As a warning, the infer package was loaded by tidymodels, so if you are using TidyModels as well, you'll have to resolve the conflict. Thanks for everyone's time!

Consider using the conflicted package. Also, reprex would have helped you spot the typo in your original example.

Two excellent tips that I hadn't seen before. This is my second SO question and second R Shiny project, so I appreciate the tips, thanks!

Make pckg::fun() a routine, avoid library(pckg); fun() in projects.

Lost 1 day because of this! Although I was on the correct way but I thought it was select.
